# Cannot set property 'textContent' of null even though it is Iinitalized and exists after the method is called

Tags: html, angular, typescript

for some reason, I cannot change the text of a span

This is the span in html

```
<span id="sortingText"></span>
```

This is the span being called within typescript

```
  sortingText : any =  document.getElementById("sortingText");
```

And this is the method where I am changing the value

```
      this.sortingText.textContent = "Sorting by Descending";
```

However when I try this, I get "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null"
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the `span` element does not exist yet when you're trying to access it with `document.getElementById`. In which method are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using Angular, why don't you use interpolation?
Add a property which contains the sort order:

```
sortingText = 'Sorting by Descending';
```

In your component's template:

```
<span>{{ sortingText }}</span>
```

To display the sort order, you have to put your property between two double braces, this way Angular will insert its value in your `span`.
You should read how to [display data](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data) in Angular docs.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged with angular so inject elements like this:

[How can I select an element in a component template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/how-can-i-select-an-element-in-a-component-template)